# JsRuntime.InvokeAsync with stream throws exception [Blazor]

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side

With .Net Core 3 Preview 7 in a Server Side Blazor project. With the latest VS 16.3.0 Preview 1.

if I load a stream and pass it through the JsRuntime to a TypeScript class, it crashes.

```cs
private async Task LoadPDF()
{
  var client = new HttpClient();
  var result = await client.GetAsync("https://www.ocr.org.uk/Images/171750-specification-accredited-as-level-gce-chemistry-a-h032.pdf");

  var bytes = await result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
  var stream = await result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

  var t2 = new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");

  await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("InitPDF", t2);

}
```

This never gets to call a method I have in a TypescriptClass:

```
async function InitPDF(file: any) { ... initialization stuff}
```

And yields:

> > System.InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream.
> >            at System.IO.Stream.get_ReadTimeout()
> >            at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfoNotNullable`4.OnWrite(WriteStackFrame& current, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
> >            at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo.Write(WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
> >            at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.HandleObject(JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonWriter writer, WriteStack& state)
> >            at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteObject(JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonWriter writer, WriteStack& state)
> >            at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Int32 originalWriterDepth, Int32 flushThreshold, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
> >            at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteCore(Utf8JsonWriter writer, PooledByteBufferWriter output, Object value, Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
> >            at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteCore(PooledByteBufferWriter output, Object value, Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
> >            at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteCoreString(Object value, Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
> >            at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize[TValue](TValue value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
> >            at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeBase.InvokeAsync[T](String identifier, Object[] args)

I can guess the problem is because of serialization problems with the stream. I have to send a stream to the javascript function as it expects a [File object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) with a blob, so instead of using a `FileStreamResult` I use a `FileContentResult` it reaches the Javascript method but it fails to init the PDF.

Any ideas if it's possible to send streams somehow through Blazor with JSInterop or any workarounds? Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue. Any help?